# Oauth 2 autentication from a desktop or console app

Tags: oauth, authorization, servicestack, console-application

I am trying to authenticate to an Oauth 2 service from a console app.

When opening the authorization server with the browser (Process.Start...) to authorize the app I should pass a callback url to receive the auth_code.

I tried to insert inside the app a webservice to be called back (servicestack), but it is not accessible from outside (localhost) and also if called is not receving the auth_code.

Is there a more effective and elegant way to do desktop authorization for Oauth 2.0 service?

Comment: I think this will help you http://developersandeep.blogspot.com/2017/03/oauth-authentication-google-facebook.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop application can use PIN based authorisation.

For example:
http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2010/02/twitter-oauth-with-net-for-the-desktop/

Comment: Check this one http://developersandeep.blogspot.com/2017/03/oauth-authentication-google-facebook.html